# Herons triangles with natural area, sides and at least two medians

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Known eight primitives Herons triangles with natural area, sides and two medians, see [A181928](https://oeis.org/A181928).

Let $a,b,c$ is half-sides, $s$ is area and $m_a,m_b,m_c$ is medians.

General properties such triangles:

$$s=(a + b + c) (b + c - a) (a + c - b) (a + b - c)$$
$$9s=(m_a + m_b + m_c) (m_b + m_c - m_a) (m_a + m_c - m_b) (m_a + m_b - m_c)$$
$$3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot8\mid s$$
$$m_a^2=2 (b^2 + c^2) - a^2$$
$$m_b^2=2 (c^2 + a^2) - b^2$$
$$m_c^2=2 (a^2 + b^2) - c^2$$
$$9a^2=2 (m_b^2 + m_c^2) - m_a^2$$
$$9b^2=2 (m_c^2 + m_a^2) - m_b^2$$
$$9c^2=2 (m_a^2 + m_b^2) - m_c^2$$
$$m_a^2 - 3 a^2 = 2 (3 b^2 - m_c^2) = 2 (3 c^2 - m_b^2) = x$$
$$m_b^2 - 3 b^2 = 2 (3 c^2 - m_a^2) = 2 (3 a^2 - m_c^2) = y$$
$$m_c^2 - 3 c^2 = 2 (3 a^2 - m_b^2) = 2 (3 b^2 - m_a^2) = z$$
$$x+y+z=0$$
$$m_a^2 + 3 a^2 = m_b^2 + 3 b^2 = m_c^2 + 3 c^2 = w$$
$$m_a^2 + m_b^2 + m_c^2 = 3 (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)=\frac{3}{2}w$$

where $x,y,z$ is some integers, $w$ is some positive integer.

Exact two half-sides is odd and one is even, exact two medians is odd and one is even.

$w$ is number of form $(km \pm 3ln)^2+3(kn \mp lm)^2=(k^2+3l^2)(m^2+3n^2)$, where $k,l,m,n$ is any positive integers.

Some relations between known primitives Herons triangles, selected by colors:

---

1) $s=1680$

$a=26, b = 73, c = 51$

$m_a= 123.2233, m_b = 35, m_c = \color{red}{97}$

$x = 13156, y = -14762, z = 1606, w = 17212$

---

2) $s=221760$

$a = 626, b = 875, c = 291\vdots\color{red}{97}$

$m_a = 1144, m_b = \color{blue}{433}, m_c = 1493.4259$

$x = 133108, y = -2109386, z = 1976278\vdots\color{red}{97}, w = 2484364\vdots\color{red}{97}$

---

3) $s = 8168160$

$a = 3673, b = 4368, c = 1241$

$m_a = 5267.6447, m_b = 3314, m_c = 7975$

$x = -12724706, y = -46255676, z = 58980382, w = 68220868$

---

4) $s = 95726400$

$a = 13816, b = 28779, c = 15155\vdots\color{blue}{433}$

$m_a = 43874\vdots\color{magenta}{21937}, m_b = 3589\vdots\color{red}{97}, m_c = 42527.0663$

$x = 1352282308, y = -2471811602, z = 1119529294\vdots\color{blue}{433}, w = 2497573444\vdots\color{blue}{433}$

---

5) $s = 302793120$

$a = 11257, b = 14791, c = 14384$

$m_a = 26918.8823, m_b = 21177, m_c = 22002$

$x = 344466078, y = -207855714, z = -136610364, w = 1104786372$

---

6) $s = 569336866560$

$a = 1823675, b = 1930456\vdots\color{magenta}{21937}, c = 185629$

$m_a = 2048523\vdots\color{blue}{433}, m_b = 1730270.7575, m_c = 3751059\vdots\color{orange}{13\cdot96181}$

$x = -5780925035346, y = -8186144209212\vdots\color{magenta}{21937}, z = 13967069244558, w = 14173817998404\vdots\color{magenta}{21937}$

---

7) $s = 8548588738240320$

$a = 46263061\vdots\color{orange}{13\cdot96181}, b = 2442655864, c = 2396426547$

$m_a = 4839082088.5150, m_b = 2350198558\vdots\color{magenta}{21937}, m_c = 2488886435\vdots\color{#0a0}{661\cdot107581}$

$x = 23410294646947500526\vdots\color{orange}{13\cdot96181}, y = -12376269747775480124, z = -11034024899172020402, w = 23423136271826038852\vdots\color{orange}{13\cdot96181}$

---

8) $s = 17293367819066194215360$

$a = 31982445133, b = 356388643246, c = 336426334971\vdots\color{#0a0}{661\cdot107581}$

$m_a = 692364218455\vdots\color{orange}{13\cdot96181}, m_b = 318430912888, m_c = 378006355503.1853$

$x = 476299580606746896423958, y = -279640348821488939749004, z = -196659231785257956674954\vdots\color{#0a0}{661\cdot107581}, w = 482436841386859028750092\vdots\color{#0a0}{661\cdot107581}$

---

Is it possible to use these relations to search next Herons triangles with natural two/three medians?